# Flag / Mark Highest ranking record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that in the end looks like this:

```
DECLARE @Rank TABLE
(
     Team VARCHAR(3),
     StatCount TINYINT,
     TeamRank TINYINT
)
INSERT INTO @Rank VALUES ('AAA', 10, 5)
INSERT INTO @Rank VALUES ('AAA', 7, 4)
INSERT INTO @Rank VALUES ('AAA', 6, 3)
INSERT INTO @Rank VALUES ('AAA', 4, 2)
INSERT INTO @Rank VALUES ('AAA', 2, 1)

SELECT * From @Rank ORDER BY TeamRank DESC
```

Now my requirement is to mark the highest rank so that the front end can highlight that record. I am open to other ideas but tried this out of the gate and it's not quite behaving as expected. So if you could point out what I am doing wrong or as mentioned another way I would be grateful.

```
SELECT 
    Team,
    StatCount,
    TeamRank,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN MAX(StatCount) = StatCount
                THEN 'True'
            ELSE
                'False'
            END
    ) AS 'HighScore'
FROM Rank
ORDER BY Team DESC;
```

Thank You

> MY Mistake!

DDL had 'AAA' for every entry but they are different. Should be 'AAA','BBB','CCC' etc.

> Thank You everyone for your answers. I apologize again for the bad DDL data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT 
    Team,
    StatCount,
    TeamRank,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN StatCount = (select max(StatCount) from @Rank)
                THEN 'True'
            ELSE
                'False'
            END
    ) AS 'HighScore'
FROM @Rank
ORDER BY Team DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `Max` with `Partition By` (assuming you're using SQL 2005 or greater):

```
SELECT 
    Team,
    StatCount,
    TeamRank,
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(StatCount) OVER (PARTITION BY Team) = StatCount
            THEN 'True'
        ELSE
            'False'
    END
    AS 'HighScore'
FROM @Rank
ORDER BY Team DESC;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17658)

Comment: @user1278561 -- np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
SELECT 
    r.*, isnull(v.b, 0) HighScore
From 
    @Rank r
    left join (select max(StatCount) m, 1 b from @Rank) v on r.StatCount = v.m
ORDER BY TeamRank DESC
```